# How to wait for one javascript to be loaded before loading the next

Tags: javascript

I want to know how I can wait for one script to load before loading the next one. For example(and also actually load another page into the page completely):

```
<html>
<script src = "script1"></script>

<script src = "script2"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#content1").load("index2.html");
});
</script>
</html>
```

So after loading script1 properly(and run all thats in there), I want to load script 2, and after that is loaded completelt, I want to load the document index2.html into this html-document.

What I have been trying so far is this but it is not working exactly as I want to.

File1: scriptOrderTest.html

```
<html>

<div id ="content1"></div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var variable1 = undefined;
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "script1.js",
      dataType: "script",
      success: () => {
        $.ajax({
          url: "script2.js",
          dataType: "script",
          success: () =>{
            // do the stuff you need
            $("#content1").load("index2.html");
          }
         });
       }
       });       
});
</script>
</html>
```

File2: script1.js

```
console.log("Starting script 1");
function revealTime(){
    console.log("Oh, I just wasted 5 seconds of my life")   
}

//This script is just wasting time
setTimeout(revealTime,5000);
```

File3: script2.js

```
console.log("Starting script 2");
function revealTime(){
    console.log("Oh, I just wasted 5 seconds of my life AGAIN") ;
    variable1 = "Pizza";
}

//This script is just wasting time
setTimeout(revealTime,5000);
```

File4: index2.html

```
<html>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    document.write("The variable is:"+variable1);   
</script>
</html>
```

Firstly, So the goal is to wait for the scripts to finish so that the variable can get a value before writing it on the page. This is not the case with the code above.

Comment: That's exactly what the code above will do. What issue are you having with it?

Answer (score 2):

You could resolve this issue by using `Promise` and chain actions together.

if you make a function that add the script and then tell's you when it is done.

something like:

```
function addScript(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Download", url);
    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.onload = function(){
      console.log(`Download done (${url})`);
      resolve(1);
    };

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

And define all the scripts you need, i just made an useless example with vue.

```
const scripts = [
  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js",
  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.1/vue-router.js"
];
```

**Sequential**

What you asked for in the question - download on at the time, delaying downloading the next script until first one is done.

```
const tasks = scripts[Symbol.iterator]();

function addAllScripts(callback){
  const url = tasks.next().value;
  if(url){
    addScript(url).then( () => { addAllScripts(callback); } );
  }else{
    callback();
  }
};
addAllScripts(() => {
  console.log("Ready");
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<p>hello world</p>'
  });
});
```

```js
function addScript(url){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   console.log("Download", url);
   var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.onload = function(){
     console.log(`Download done (${url})`);
      resolve(1);
    };

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  });
}

const scripts = [
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js",
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.1/vue-router.js"
];

const tasks = scripts[Symbol.iterator]();

function addAllScripts(callback){
   const url = tasks.next().value;
    if(url){
      addScript(url).then( () => { addAllScripts(callback); } );
    }else{
      callback();
    }
};
addAllScripts(() => {
 console.log("Ready");
          new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            template: '<p>hello world</p>'
          });
});
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Parallel**

Optimal solution, faster execution - add all scripts at once, and wait until all are done

```
const tasks = scripts.map(addScript);

Promise.all( tasks )
       .then(function(){
          console.log("Ready");
          new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            template: '<p>hello world</p>'
          });
       });
```

```js
function addScript(url){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   console.log("Download", url);
   var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.onload = function(){
     console.log(`Download done (${url})`);
      resolve(1);
    };

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  });
}

const scripts = [
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js",
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.1/vue-router.js"
];

const tasks = scripts.map(addScript);

Promise.all( tasks )
       .then(function(){
          console.log("Ready");
          new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            template: '<p>hello world</p>'
          });
    });
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: You have written very nice code, I just don't understand it. Maybe I am not enough experienced as a java developer yet ...

Comment: javascript* ;) - what part do you not understand, then i can try and clear it up a bit.

Comment: The code about the SEQUENTIAL solution code snippet. Maybe you could write some comments on each line about what is happening. I am also unsure of the flow of the code execution, where does it start and end and so on.

Comment: I mean, you use like promises and callbacks and the object Vue() i don't have a clue about. Everything is stuff that I don't know how to use yet properly : p

Comment: Ah yes sure, well you dont need the Vue stuff, was just as the scripts i loaded was vue, so it was just to demo the script. but you can see some comments here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lke59208/10/

Comment: @keja I can't believe you didnt have a single upvote. This was a great answer. Especially your parallel script loader using map. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NickDiv Happy you found it usefull, if i had to write it today, ill probably go with the async/await syntax instead of .then for a bit more clean and readable code.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in document.ready:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url1,
  dataType: "script",
  success: () => {
     $.ajax({
       url: url2,
       dataType: "script",
       success: () =>{
         // do the stuff you need
       }
   });
  }
  });
```

Comment: I added some info to my comment, can you check if I understood you correctly maybe?

Comment: It is not working exactly as I wanted, firstly, script 2 is not waiting for script 1 to finish its stuff before being loaded into the page. I think i will paste the code in my files to show what I have done.

Comment: If you put setTimeout, then yes, second script starts loading before script1 setTimeout function is invoked in 5 seconds

Comment: Because the problem is, It don't have control over what happens in script1. It is another persons work which I cannot change. But I don't want to load my stuff before his scripts have executed everything properly.

Comment: In that case you need to wait till all setTimeout staff is done in script1. Where us no other way if you cannot change script1